# Incrementing array of pointers

Tags: c

I've been trying to increment array of pointers to and assigning them to be addresses of an array but I can't seem to figure it out.

Input:

```
void * myParam(unsigned int *argv[]){

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("Block[%d] = Pointer Address %x\n", i, *(argv + i));
    }

    return *argv;
}



int main(){

    unsigned int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    unsigned int *ptr;
    ptr = arr;
    ptr = myParam(&ptr);

}
```

Output:

```
Block[0] = Pointer Address ea6d6b60

Block[1] = Pointer Address 1

Block[2] = Pointer Address 3

Block[3] = Pointer Address 5

Block[4] = Pointer Address f6770089
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an array of pointers. You have a pointer to one pointer (=an array of one pointer).
Subscripting that `argv` with anything but 0 (or 1 if you don't dereference that) is undefined. After you dereference it once, you can add 0 through 4 (and possibly dereference those to obtain the array values (1 through 5)).

```
#include <stdio.h>
void * myParam(unsigned int *argv[]){

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("Block[%u] = Pointer Address %p, value=%u\n", i, (void*)(*argv + i), 
                                                                (*argv)[i]);
    }

    return *argv;
}

int main(){

    unsigned int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    unsigned int *ptr;
    ptr = arr;
    ptr = myParam(&ptr);
}
```